# Testing placeholder prop in imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component in which I've imported `react-date-picker`, which doesn't have the ability to set the placeholder as prop for the input fields, so I've used a workaround found (in `componentDidMount`) on its github page [here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker/issues/6).

here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';

class AlertModal extends React.Component {

...

  componentDidMount(){
     document.querySelector('.react-date-picker__button__input__day').placeholder = 'Day';
     document.querySelector('.react-date-picker__button__input__month').placeholder = 'Month';
     document.querySelector('.react-date-picker__button__input__year').placeholder = 'Year'
   }

    render = () => {
       return (
          <div>
             <DatePicker
              onChange={this.handleToDate}
              value={this.state.toDate}
              minDate={this.state.minToDate}
              calendarIcon={null}
              showLeadingZeros={true}
            />
          </div>
       )
    }


    }
```

The issue I have is in my test, when I try the below it fails with: `Cannot set property 'placeholder' of undefined`.

```
describe('datepicker placehoder overrides', () => {
  let component;
  const mockSubmit = jest.fn();
  const mockCancel = jest.fn();

  it('should be DD for days', () => {
    component = mount(<AlertModal submit={mockSubmit} cancel={mockCancel} />);
    expect(
      component
        .find('.react-date-picker__inputGroup__day')
        .at(0)
        .props().placeholder
    ).toBeEqual('DD');
  });
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: Not directly related to an answer, but you may want to try to avoid direct dom manipulation in react. Consider using setState instead of querySelector.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [Jest:](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery)

> Jest ships with jsdom which simulates a DOM environment as if you were
>   in the browser. This means that every DOM API that we call can be
>   observed in the same way it would be observed in a browser!

So you just have to add the relevant HTML markup to the DOM before proceeding the test.

```
describe('datepicker placehoder overrides', () => {
  let component;
  document.body.innerHTML = `<div>
    <input class="react-date-picker__button__input__day" />
    <input class="react-date-picker__button__input__month" />
    <input class="react-date-picker__button__input__year" />
  </div>`;
  const mockSubmit = jest.fn();
  const mockCancel = jest.fn();

  it('should be DD for days', () => {
    component = mount(<AlertModal submit={mockSubmit} cancel={mockCancel} />);
    expect(
      component
        .find('.react-date-picker__inputGroup__day')
        .at(0)
        .props().placeholder
    ).toBeEqual('DD');
  });
});
```